# ASP.NET membership database not working from SQL Server instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, asp.net-membership

net web application with membership controls. By default the membership databases (ASPNETDB.mdf) got created in the APP_Data folder. It's working fine from there, but I had to move the databases to SQL server instance.

I copied the MDF and LDF files to another folder and attached it as a new database in my SQL server instance. then I changed the connection string in the web.config file to point to the new location.

But the problem is that the new database location is not working. I am always getting login failed exception. I am sure that the credentials supplied in the connection string are correct, because the same credentials are working in a different application.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Please post the connection string and the error message!

Comment: Sometimes when you create a db under app_data, it's not in sql instance. You have to move it to right sql instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the `aspnet_regsql.exe` from the .net command line to register a database to support the different providers you need, including Membership, Role, or Profile.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(v=vs.80).aspx